# python pysvn creating default folders on initialization

Tags: python, svn, pysvn

I'm using [pysvn](http://pysvn.stage.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html) module to control subversion activities.
And for the moment, I'm still testing. However I notice something weird.
When I'm using

```
import pysvn
client = pysvn.client('svn_dir_path')
```

to initialize a client object.

1.In one repository, the svn URL goes like:

`svn://host:port/auto_test/case_manage/static/file`

pysvn create a "auth" folder, "config" file, "servers" file, and README.txt file.(with nothing important inside these files)

[image]

2.In another repository, where the svn URL goes like:

```
http://localhost:port/svn/minder_files
```

And in this case, nothing is created.

So could someone explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You told SVN to create a config folder for you.
If the docuemntation was not clear let me know.

From the documentation at http://pysvn.stage.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client

```
client = pysvn.Client()
client = pysvn.Client( config_dir )
```

The default subversion configuration directory is used if the config_dir is omitted or set to ''.

The configuration directory is automatically created if it is missing.

A Client object can only be used on one thread at a time. If two threads attempt to call methods of Client at the same time one of the threads will get a pysvn.ClientError exception with the value 'client in use on another thread'.

Barry (pysvn maintainer)

Answer (score 0):

After some testing(well, I'm still not sure about my conclusion), I think the reason why `pysvn` is creating such folders&files is because in:

```
client = pysvn.client('svn_dir_path')
```

The '`svn_dir_path`' is not the root path of the svn repository but certain sub-path.
Hope this helps somebody someday.

Comment: well. that's still not for sure